# Singleton class destructor fails to clean up (SDL_Quit) on MinGW

Tags: c++, singleton, mingw, sdl-2

My SDL program does not return when running on MinGW (below). If I move `SDL_Quit` outside the singleton class's dtor to the end of main, it no longer has a problem. So I assume it's a problem of order of construction/destruction. But there's nothing else that needs destructing. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <SDL.h>

class ExceptionType {};

class SDL_DisplayType
{
public:
    static SDL_DisplayType& Instance ()
    {
        static SDL_DisplayType myInstance;
        return myInstance;
    }   

    SDL_Window*   sdlWindow_;
    SDL_Renderer* sdlRenderer_;

private:
    SDL_DisplayType  ();    
    ~SDL_DisplayType (); 
};

SDL_DisplayType::SDL_DisplayType() 
{
    if (SDL_Init (SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0) throw ExceptionType ();

    sdlWindow_ = SDL_CreateWindow ("",SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,640, 480, 0);
    if (! sdlWindow_) throw ExceptionType ();

    sdlRenderer_ = SDL_CreateRenderer (sdlWindow_, -1, 0);
    if (! sdlRenderer_) throw ExceptionType ();
}

SDL_DisplayType::~SDL_DisplayType ()
{
    SDL_Quit (); //<-- Move this to end of main and problem goes away
}

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    //draw something, just so I can call SDL_DisplayType::Instance
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(SDL_DisplayType::Instance ().sdlRenderer_, 255, 255, 255, 255);
    SDL_RenderDrawLine    (SDL_DisplayType::Instance ().sdlRenderer_, 0, 0, 100, 100);
    SDL_RenderPresent     (SDL_DisplayType::Instance ().sdlRenderer_);

    while (true) //wait for key hit
    {
        SDL_Event sdlEvent; 
        if (SDL_WaitEvent (&sdlEvent) == 0) throw ExceptionType ();
        if (sdlEvent.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) break ;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Makefile, in case it's useful:

```
INCLUDE_FLAGS   =   -I..\..\SDL2-MinGW\SDL2\i686-w64-mingw32\include\SDL2       \
                    -I..\..\SDL2-MinGW\SDL2_image\i686-w64-mingw32\include\SDL2 \
                    -I..\..\SDL2-MinGW\SDL2_mixer\i686-w64-mingw32\include\SDL2 \
                    -I..\..\SDL2-MinGW\SDL2_ttf\i686-w64-mingw32\include\SDL2   

LIBRARY_PATH    =   -L..\..\SDL2-MinGW\SDL2\i686-w64-mingw32\lib        \
                    -L..\..\SDL2-MinGW\SDL2_image\i686-w64-mingw32\lib  \
                    -L..\..\SDL2-MinGW\SDL2_mixer\i686-w64-mingw32\lib  \
                    -L..\..\SDL2-MinGW\SDL2_ttf\i686-w64-mingw32\lib                    

a.out:  main.o 
    g++ -g $(LIBRARY_PATH) main.o -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_mixer -lSDL2_ttf -L. 

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -g -c  $(INCLUDE_FLAGS) main.cpp
```

Comment: can you elaborate on "does not return"?

Comment: There's no problem shown in this code as far as I can see. Present a [mcve]

Comment: By "Does not return" I mean I never get another command prompt (unless I hit Ctrl-C).

Comment: This is an MCVE in that it's short (I hope) and it does exhibit the undesirable behavior I described. On MinGW. It's fine on Unix. Which suggests I'm doing some kind of undefined behavior.

Comment: It's possible mingw-w64 has issues with static constructors/destructors. You could probably get a good answer on #mingw-w64 (IRC) or on the mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ there is no constraint on the order of destruction of static data (when compiled in separeted files). Then, never use (directly or not) static data in the destructor of a singleton, because you can't know if the data still exists.

In your case, you probably try to call some SDL stuff already destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

> But there's nothing else that needs destructing. What am I doing wrong?

Well, by looking at your `SDL_DisplayType`'s *destructor*:

```
SDL_DisplayType::~SDL_DisplayType ()
{
    SDL_Quit ();
}
```

You can realize that the two `SDL_DisplayType`'s data members – `sdlWindow_` and `sdlRenderer_` – are created in the *constructor*, but they are not destroyed here, in the corresponding destructor.

Consider calling [`SDL_DestroyRenderer()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_DestroyRenderer) and [`SDL_DestroyWindow()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_DestroyWindow) – in this order – in `SDL_DisplayType`'s destructor just before calling `SDL_Quit()`, i.e.:

```
SDL_DisplayType::~SDL_DisplayType () {
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(sdlRenderer_);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(sdlWindow_);
    SDL_Quit ();
}
```

Comment: Oh, I took those out to make it an MCVE. They were in earlier, with the same undesirable behavior, alas. It was worth trying, though!